# How to remove zero slice/images in a Nd matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I have a Nd matrix `A` with the dimension of (256,256,100). In which,`256x256` are height and width, and `100` is the number of images/slice. In the `100` images, they have some images are zero (only background), other images are non-zero (including background and foreground). The background intensity is 0 and foreground intensity is 1. I want to delete/remove zero slices/images from the matrix A. How could I do it in python efficiently?

This is my implementation but I think we can do better

```
import numpy as np
h, w, c = A.shape
for i in range (c): 
   A_slice=A[:,:,i]
   sum_in= np.sum(A_slice)
   if (sum_in==0):
      np.delete(A,A_slice)
```

**Update:** Sorry I missing one requirement. I have a vector `B` with the shape of (100,). It contained the id of each slice from 1 to 100. When we remove the slice in the matrix A, I also want to remove its id/index in the vector B. Thanks

Comment: `A = A[...,A.sum((0,1)) != 0]`?

Comment: Great solution. I missing one requirement. Please wait I am updating

Comment: I updated it. Could you look at it and answer? I will accept it

Comment: And `B = B[A.sum((0,1)) != 0]`?

Comment: Thanks @kitman0804, I got the error such as `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 100 but corresponding boolean dimension is 20`

Comment: I think you should run `B = ...` then @Yakym's `A = ...`, or use @Yakym Pirozhenko's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compute a boolean mask for "zero" images as

```
zero_mask = A.sum((0,1)) == 0
```

To remove corresponding images, we can use

```
A = A[..., ~zero_mask]
B = B[~zero_mask]
```

Comment: This is my expected solution. Thanks

Comment: fyi https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html